# Method Creating custom tokens will create uid if not exist in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I using firebase. I using method: Creating custom tokens. When i look document in firebase https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/create-custom-tokens .

```
const uid = 'some-uid';

admin
  .auth()
  .createCustomToken(uid)
  .then((customToken) => {
    // Send token back to client
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error creating custom token:', error);
  });
```

I have a question
If i don't have uid in firebase, it will create it ? If i have uid, i only create custom token and send back to client. I look document and i don't see document specific it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to make an API call to create a user in Firebase when you're using custom authentication. Calling `createCustomToken` on the server, and then signing on the client with the resulting ID token, is all that is needed.

---

There is no separate step to *create* the UID for a custom provider. You create the custom token with the UID and other claims you want, send it to the client over a secure connection, and the client can then sign in to Firebase with that token.

For Firebase services the ID token, and the UID in it, are ephemeral - since it is your server (where you run the Admin SDK), and the client that maintain them. That's the reason a separate step to create the UID in Firebase is not necessary.

Comment: Frank van Puffelen  Base on answer, I need create uid i must call method createUser. createCustomToken not create user for me. Another way,  createCustomToken not create uid if it not exist. Because i want create uid and createCustomToken one method.

Comment: There is no need to make an API call to create a user in Firebase when you're using custom authentication. Calling `createCustomToken` on the server, and then signing on the client with the resulting ID token, is all that is needed.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, uid is required and **whatever you write into the uid parameter it becomes a user** that you can check in the firebase console.

If you create random **uid**s every time, those will all be new users. So if you don't want firebase users, don't use firebase auth.