# Firebase custom token revocation

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

If it's stated explicitly if the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens) then I missed it, but given it lets you supply an arbitrary UID when creating a custom auth token with the Firebase admin SDK, I assume a corresponding user record of sorts is implicitly created. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66253584/method-creating-custom-tokens-will-create-uid-if-not-exist-in-firebase) post suggests the same.

Custom token creation appears to work fine, but when I go to revoke refresh tokens for the same UID I receive the below error:

*There is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may have been deleted.*

I've verified through debug the UID is the same at token creation and revocation, btw. I can supply code if it helps but really just asking on a conceptual level.

Because I'm working on back end code ahead of client side changes to be made by someone else, no code yet exists to actually login with this custom token. So I'm wondering if perhaps post client login the above error would disappear. But even if that turns out to be the case, how are you meant to revoke an as-yet unused token? Seems like a security headache to me.

We do already use custom tokens btw, so a similar process is proven, but this is for a pre-existing (email/pw) Firebase user.

So I guess I'm asking several related questions:

1. Am I right in thinking no pre-existing user is required for custom tokens?
2. Must they be used to log in before you can revoke tokens associated with the UID?
3. If yes to 2, does anyone know of best practice to manage the retained dangling token risk? Say a client account is deleted before the token is used.